# Javascript funcionando sem declarar variavel

Tags: javascript

Estou praticando Javascript e resolvi fazer um simples To Do List.

Percebi que meu programa identifica a variavel `tableTask` memso sem eu declarar ela. Eu exclui a linha `let tableTask = document.querySelector("#tableTask")` e ela continuar funcionado.

Eu não declarei em nenhum outro lugar. Como isso está funcionando?

```js
var quantTasks = 1

const buttonForm = document.querySelector("#buttonForm")
buttonForm.addEventListener("click", function() {
    event.preventDefault()
    tempTr = createTr()
    createTd(tempTr)
    let tableTask = document.querySelector("#tableTask")
    tableTask.appendChild(tempTr)
    quantTasks++
    document.querySelector("#formTask").reset()
})

function createTr() {
    let tempTr = document.createElement("tr")
    tempTr.classList.add("task"+quantTasks)
    return tempTr
}

function createTd() {
    let tempIndice = document.createElement("td")
    tempIndice.classList.add("infoIndice")
    tempIndice.textContent = quantTasks
    let tempTask = document.createElement("td")
    tempTask.classList.add("infoTask")
    let textTask = document.querySelector("#formTask").inputTask.value
    tempTask.textContent = textTask
    tempTr.appendChild(tempIndice)
    tempTr.appendChild(tempTask)

}

function addToTable(tempRow) {
    
}
```

```css
#infoTask {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #c7d5e6;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
#infoIndice {
    background-color: #c7d5e6;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Easy Task</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody id="tableTask">
            <tr id="infoBar">
                <td id="infoIndice">Nº</td>
                <td id="infoTask">Task</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <form action="" id="formTask">
        <input id="inputTask" type="text" name="inputTask">
        <button id="buttonForm">Task</button>
    </form>
    <script src="task.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso é porque você declarou um `id` com o nome `tableTask` no seu HTML. O seu navegador indexa os ids que ele encontra no HTML, e os adiciona na sua `window`, por isso você pode acessa-los como variáveis globais. Porém esse comportamento só existe por questão de compatibilidades com websites antigos, não é um padrão, e por isso deve ser desencorajado, pois navegadores diferentes podem não ter esse mesmo comportamento. Procure inicializar suas variáveis manualmente.

Comment: Percebi que a variavel tinha o mesmo nome do Id mais queria alguem com mais experiencia falando sobre pois achei que seria muita "ganbiarra" deixar dessa forma. Obrigado pela informação.